# I get an error when I put an imaginary number in a column of a table with column specifier S (from siunitx package)

Tags: tables, siunitx

Using the [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package. I have a table with column specifier `S`
if I then put an imaginary number in it comes up with a compile time error:

```
! siunitx error: "table-partial-number"
!
! No space reserved for a complex on line 20.
!
! See the siunitx documentation for further information.
...
| The number in the current table cell contains a complex part,
| but you did not reserve any space to print it:
| it will be missing in the output.
```

It sounds like I need to enter in some optional argument to make this work but I don't know what that is from reading the manual.

Here's some code (remove the i in the left column to make to compile):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}


\begin{table}
   \centering
   \sisetup{table-alignment=center}
   \begin{tabular}{ S S S S }
   \toprule
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{things} & \\
          a             &  b             &  c             & {related things}\\
   \midrule
          1             &  1             &  1             &   1    \\
          2             &  1             &  2             &   4    \\
          3i             &  2             &  3             &  18    \\
          4             &  2             &  4             &  32    \\
      \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Currently "this won't work". I added complex numbers to support certain edge-case uses where you see, for example, imaginary frequencies. Dealing with these in tables has not exactly been a priority: there are a large number of possible alignment cases that I'm not too keen on taking on. I've always imagined that in a table, the complex part would in any case have a column to itself and be divide by i, for example 'Imaginary frequency/i cm^-1'.

Comment: To elaborate further, what alignment would you expect in column 1? Should the `3` come under the `2`, or after it? If the former happens, what then occurs if the input is `1 + i`?

Comment: Indeed, I see the general alignment problem when a real component is included. In this case I imagined the numbers being aligned as though there were no `i' after and then the `i' being appended to the right. In the case of this table with nothing after the radix, i could set `table-figures-decimal=0' and add `\textit{i}' after the imaginary frequencies.

Comment: What do you think, is this sensible or am i missing a trick.

Comment: @User1269: The problem for me (as a package author) is that simplifications which seems okay to individual end-users tend to come back to bother me! I've got 'look at tables again' pencilled in for v2.3, so I will see what I can do for imaginary numbers. I'm hoping to have a go at this next month.

Comment: Yes, I do some coding myself (not in latex) and I know of the problems unleashed when you try to make something work in a more general way. In terms of a short term fix, so I can make this work. Do you think my solution is sensible? or is there something simpler? thanks

Comment: @Joseph: Please turn your comments into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

(More of a comment, but converted to an answer as there is not a better one.)

Currently "this won't work". I added complex numbers to support certain edge-case uses where you see, for example, imaginary frequencies. Dealing with these in tables has not exactly been a priority: there are a large number of possible alignment cases that I'm not too keen on taking on. I've always imagined that in a table, the complex part would in any case have a column to itself and be divide by i, for example `Imaginary frequency/i cm$^-1$`.